# Enable scrolling with trackpoint+middleclick on wayland

Tags: fedora, xorg, thinkpad, wayland, libinput

I installed Fedora 25 on my Thinkpad E470 and the Trackpoint works well.
But I cannot use the middle button (the button between left and right mouse click) to scroll.

Referring to this [source](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/scrolling.html#button_scrolling) it should be possible.

I found several hints on how to enable this feature on Xorg but I have no clue how to get it work with wayland.

Can anybody help out?

[image: Related button and trackpoint]

OS Info:

```
 Fedora 25
 Gnome 3.22.2
 Wayland 1.12.0
 libinput 1.6.3
```

**Update:**
Also `libinput-debug-events` does not recognize pressing the middle mouse button. `libinput-list-devices` prints the following:

```
Device:           TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint
Kernel:           /dev/input/event8
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

Comment: Does it work without Wayland (X11 session?).

Comment: It is not working out of the box on X11.

Comment: I noticed that with `xev` the middle button is not recognized.

Comment: If i remember well it worked for me with thinkpad e440s so it is probably sending some different events in the new thinkpad and needs an adjuatment for a driver.

Comment: nope. Not working on T440s with X11 (partially because I don't have the middle button). But on Dell Latitude E6440 it worked just fine (with Ubuntu 16.10) so there is certainly some difference in drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found out the linux kernel had a bug that prevented Fedora from detecting the trackpoint.
As far as I know only trackpoints from the new *70 series are affected.

The bug was fixed in [Linux 4.13](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/diff/drivers/input/mouse/trackpoint.c?id=v4.12&id2=v4.13).

Answer (score 0):

`xf86-input-libinput` - I'm running this one on X11, but can it be X related? If yes, try to install xWayland so you can run X related things on Wayland...

By the way, `xev` requires  manual interaction while `libinput` (specifically for track-point middle button usage) does not. As I'm lazy, I use `libinput`.

Comment: There is no such package `xf86-input-libinput` in the fedora repos.. I mean I have `libinput` and `xorg-x11-drv-libinput` installed. But it doesn't help.